# PostreSQL execute a default query when no row are returned

Tags: postgresql, row, default-value

I need to calculate the average score of a **list of userId.**

I have a table "user_place_score" (user_id / place_id/ score). 
Sometimes I do not have the score for a user_id so I need to fetch a "default" score in a the "default_place_score" table (place_id / score).

Is is possible in PostreSQL to do this in one query ? For a a given list of users and one place_id select all their score in the user_place_score and if now row found take the score found if the default_place_score table ?

Basically I want to avoid doing this kind of stuff:

```
for (Integer userId : userIds) {
  score = (query to fetch the score for this userId)
  if (score == null)
    defaultScore = (query to fetch the default score for this PlaceId)

  total = total + defaultScore
}

//return the average
return total/numberOfUser
```

Thank you!